# MultiByteToWideChar as mbrtowc

Tags: c, winapi, encoding

As `man 3p mbrtowc` says, there are four result types which it may return: *`0`* if bytes would be decoded to NUL wide character, *`(size_t)-2`* if the sequence is truncated, *`(size_t)-1`* if the sequence is illegal, and other values from varying zero to the length of the multibyte sequence. Everything is clear enough here. How about WinAPI?

There is a `MultiByteToWideChar` function, which may set *`ERROR_NO_UNICODE_TRANSLATION`* (which corresponds to *`(size_t)-1`* for `mbrtowc`), *`ERROR_INVALID_FLAGS`* and *`ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`* (which I think indicate the same as *`EINVAL`*). I doubt about *`ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER`*: it *could* mean the same thing as *`(size_t)-2`* for `mbrtowc`, but from the documentation it seems that it just means that the buffer of wide characters is not large enough to store converted characters.

What are the common practices for retrieving such a functionality (if ever possible) without reimplementing `mbrtowc` and friends? Are there `MultiByteToWideChar` alternatives, which work as `mbrtowc` in Windows? Thanks in advance!

P. S. Please don't advice to use UTF-8 here. I'm already using it everywhere where possible. However, I have to deal with Windows code pages, and right now I'm looking for a good way to convert multibyte string to wide character sequence and then to array of Unicode glyphs (depending on the sizeof(wchar_t), it means either direct conversion to UTF-32 or decoding from UTF-16 first). I'd like to know if one must stop conversion due to illegal multibyte sequence or if conversion may be continued since the given multibyte sequence is incomplete. Thus please don't ask why I ever use `wchar_t` too: I really have to deal with code pages in some parts of the code before converting it to either UTF-8 or UTF-32, so that's not my own choice.

Comment: Instead of re-implementing it, consider using the [existing implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5wazc5ys.aspx).

Comment: I was thinking about this; sadly, Microsoft's `mbrtowc` deals with locales, not with code pages.

Comment: No idea why you quoted the man page.  Or why you are not just using MultiByteToWideChar() if you think you need it.  What is the actual problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution that allows to deal with [`MultiByteToWideChar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/dd319072%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) more properly if you use non-UTF encoding (since I use my own functions to deal with UTF-8, UTF-16 and UTF-32, this approach seems the best way to go).

All one has to do is to iterate over every singular byte in buffer (either null-terminated C string or some data). On every character one has to either call [`IsDBCSLeadByteEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/dd318667%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function or use [`GetCPInfoEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/dd318667%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with [`CPINFOEX`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/dd317781%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure to check if current byte shall be followed by the next. If there is a byte next, one must use `MultiByteToWideChar` on two bytes (i.e. count of bytes is two); if there is no byte after current byte, it means the same as result *`(size_t)-2`* for `mbrtowc` call. If conversion fails, result is the same as *`(size_t)-1`* for `mbrtowc` call.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're talking about Microsoft's CRT for Windows, the only outcome that it will ever have from getting an error calling MultiByteToWideChar() setting EILSEQ and returning -1.  The Microsoft SDK source code is publicly-available (most of it, anyway) and I suggest briefly studying it to clarify the situation.

To answer the "common practices" part of your question, I'll answer for my current company.  For cases where we need to get precise and semantics, the C library consistently lets you down, generally either by pigeonholing errors (as in this case) or having bugs, or just not having the same degree of error-handling quality as your code might.  So we directly call MultiByteToWideChar() from a wrapper that has the semantics we want.

Depending on how crazy you want to get, even MultiByteToWideChar() might not have the degree of error-handling you want.  Microsoft covers up a lot of the details.  If you need really precise semantics, you might want to go with a stand-alone library, like IBM's ICU, that will give you all of the stuff you might need.

It all comes down to what degree of precision you're going for in dealing with problems.